# How to show only 20 object from Array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using angular 7. I have initialized an array given as:

```
 cacheDatas=[];
```

Here cacheData has 1000 of object which are initialized to `cacheDatas` but I only need 20 object.

```
getDataOfCache(cacheData:any){
       this.cacheDatas=cacheData;
       this.cacheDatas.slice(0,20);
     console.log(this.cacheDatas);
  }
```

I tried to implement the slice method but it is not working. The value cacheData:any is:
[image]

Comment: you aren't assigning back the value `this.cacheDatas.slice(0,20);` to `this.cacheDatas`

Comment: can u show me the example

Comment: if you want upvote then please post the line of code,i will tick it

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to assign the value for the variable: `cacheDatas` after slice.

```
this.cacheDatas = this.cacheDatas.slice(0,20);
```

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3d4ypz

Answer (score 0):

you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method but this method will method changes the contents of an array by removing

```
    this.cacheDatas.splice(20);
```

another option is the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method same as you question but this methos method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object

```
 const result = this.cacheDatas.slice(0,20);
 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method does not modify the array but returns a new array with the required elements. So you can use the below to solve your problem -

```
getDataOfCache(cacheData:any){
       this.cacheDatas=cacheData;
       this.cacheDatas=this.cacheDatas.slice(0,20);
       console.log(this.cacheDatas);
  }
```

Or you can use the [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method (note the change in spelling). It will modify the original array as per the given input. If only one index is given as input, then it will remove all the elements from that index to the end of the array. So you can use this code as well -

```
getDataOfCache(cacheData:any){
       this.cacheDatas=cacheData;
       this.cacheDatas.splice(20);
       console.log(this.cacheDatas);
  }
```